# Equivalence of the two definitions of integral of a non-negative function.

Tags: measure-theory, definition, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,\mathcal S,\mu)$ be a measure space and $f:X\to [0,\infty]$ be a function.Then the first definition of integral of $f$ is as follows:

> $\int_X fd\mu=\sup\limits_{0\leq s\leq f,s \text{ simple}}\int_X sd\mu$.

For the second definition we need to define $\mathcal L(f,P)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^m \mu(A_j)\inf\limits_{A_j} f$ where $P$ is the partition $A_1\cup A_2\cup \dots \cup A_m=X$ and $A_j$'s are disjoint $\mathcal S$-measurable.Now comes the second definition:

> $\int_X fd\mu=\sup\limits_{\text{partition }P} \mathcal L(P,f)$.

I want to show that these two definitions are equivalent.Call the first integral $\int_1 fd\mu$ and the second one by $\int_2 fd\mu$.Then I have shown that $\int_2 fd\mu\leq \int_1 fd\mu$ because $\{\mathcal L(P,f):P$ is an $\mathcal S$-partition of $X\}\subset \{\int_X sd\mu|s:X\to [0,\infty)$ is  simple and $0\leq s\leq f\}$,so I take supremum on both sides.I want to know first whether I am correct upto this point.I think I may run into problem if some $\inf f=\infty$.Next I want to know how to show the other way round.Can someone help me with this?Can monotone convergence theorem help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $s$ is a simple function with $0 \leq s \leq f$ the we can write $s= \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_j\chi_{A_j}$ where $(A_j)$ is a partition of $X$ by sets from $\mathcal S$. Also, $\int_X sd\mu=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_j\mu (A_j)  $. Hence, $\int_X sd\mu \leq \mathcal L (P,f) \leq \int_2 fd\mu$. Now take supremum over $s$ to finish.

Comment: @Kishalay Sarkar Thanks for editing.

Comment: You can elaborate further.Let $0\leq s\leq f$ then $a_j\leq f(x)$ for all $x\in A_j$ so $a_j\leq \inf\limits_{A_j} f\implies \sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_j\mu(A_j)\leq \mathcal L(P,f)\leq \int_2 f d\mu$.

Comment: Please tell me if the inequality I did in question is alright even in $\infty$ case.

Comment: There is no problem with $\infty$. @KishalaySarkar